# chrome extension v3 get selected text, display contextmenu and send to restful api

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm new to Chrome extension development and I have searched for an extension example on how to do this but most examples are for manifest v2 and I need it for v3. I have tried converting the v2 examples I have found but have had no success.

The extension should do the following:

1. When the user selects text on the page and right-clicks it should display a context-menu (ex: Option 1, Option 2, etc)
2. When the user clicks on one of the context-menu options the extension sends the selected text, the URL of the page and the selected context-menu option to a restful API.

Thanks

Comment: The question is too broad as it contains several tasks, each one is trivial by itself so it's unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using selected text in contextMenu chrome (manifest version 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72546526/using-selected-text-in-contextmenu-chrome-manifest-version-3)

Comment: @wOxxOm I saw that one as well but it's only partially posted...the solution doesn't show the manifest for example.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I understand your point regarding the question being too broad. I will search individually each task and maybe I can cobble something together

Comment: The only extra thing you need in manifest.json is the permission as [shown in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#manifest).